# How do I create a playback device under pavucontrol?

Tags: linux, audio, alsa

First, I will confess my lack of understanding of Linux audio.  It looks big, confusing and somewhat scary.

What I am trying to do is pipe audio from the HAM Radio program `gqrx` into the digital speech decoder `dsd` as seen in other examples floating around the web.

But after creating a virtual sound device in `/dev/dsp/` using:

```
padsp -- dsd -i /dev/dsp -o /dev/dsp -fa -ma
```

I do not see dsd listed under playback devices when I open `pavucontrol` (but I do see `gqrx` listed)?  I have tried many different things but cannot get `dsd` listed under playback devices.  This step is required to go any further and use the other audio sinks to listen to the output.

Thank-you in advance...

Comment: You need to load a PA module to create a virtual sink and source, and then you can connect them to the programs.

Comment: Okay... how do I go about creating a PA module and a virtual sink?  Thank-you.

Comment: You don't create one, you pick [one of the existing ones](https://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/PulseAudio/Documentation/User/Modules/).

Comment: Okay sorry I am not trying to be a pain but I really have no experience with this stuff.  I need baby steps.  Which one do I want to use?  There are over 30 modules listed...  none of them called DSD.  Can I just load all modules and make that the default?  Someone said to "modprobe snd_aloop" but that did nothing either.  Why can't I just choose which ones to load from inside pavucontrol?  Isn't that the point of it?

Comment: Maybe have a look at https://askubuntu.com/questions/895216/how-to-route-pulse-audio-device-into-alsa-loopback-virtual-microphone/896355#896355

Answer (score 2):

To make Linux audio less scary, a quick overview over Linux audio history (google for more details):

The first widely used sound system on Linux was the [Open Sound System (OSS)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open_Sound_System), which used devices like `/dev/dsp`. Now OSS is obsolete, but there are still old programs that exclusively use it, so nearly all other audio system provide an emulation layer, like `padsp` from Pulseaudio.

Today, the basic audio system used in Linux is [ALSA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Advanced_Linux_Sound_Architecture). It has become part of the kernel, and provides drivers for the hardware. Devices look like `/dev/snd/pcmC0D0p` (card 0, device 0, playback) or `/dev/snd/pcmC1D2c` (card 1, device 2, capture), but everybody uses a library (`libalsa`) instead the devices directly, because you can't pipe stuff into them as for `/dev/dsp`. ALSA can be configured via `/.asoundrc`, but this configuration file is not very user friendly.

Most desktop systems today also come with Pulseaudio. It runs a top of ALSA, and not only provides a compatibility layer for OSS, but also a compatibility layer for programs trying to access ALSA (using a pseudo-ALSA device called `pulse`). You've already seen `pavucontrol`, there's also `pacmd` and `pactl` to control Pulseaudio from the commandline (don't ask me why there's two of them ...).

Back to your problem. What you should see in both the playback tab and the recording tab of `pavucontrol` after running

```
padsp -- dsd -i /dev/dsp -o /dev/dsp -fa -ma
```

is something like `OSS emulation[dsd]`. Possibly you were confused by the "OSS emulation" part (which is there because `padsp` does OSS emulation). If you really don't see that, please edit your question with any errors that may appear after running the command above, and also with the output of `pactl list short clients` while the command is running. Then we can try to debug what is going wrong.

In Pulseaudio, every *audio sink* (e.g., playback hardware of your sound card) also has an associated `.monitor` *audio source*. You pipe audio from one application into another application by connecting the second application to a `.monitor` source of the sink the first application is playing into. You can do that in `puvacontrol`, as described in the tutorials you already read.

In your case, you want to monitor the sound output from `gqrx`, so you can just use the hardware audio sink. You *could* also create a "virtual" audio sink with associated `.monitor` source, but then you wouldn't hear the audio.

`snd_aloop` is a different (and somewhat complicated) way to do loopback in ALSA only. As you are running Pulseaudio anyway, **don't** use it.

**Edit**

I recreated your problem following [this blog entry](https://marcinkowski.ca/blog/2014/02/19/decoding-dmr-radio-using-rtlsdr-gqrx-and-pulseaudio) on how to set up `dsd` and `gqrx`, except I get five streams (what you see under Playback and Record in `pavucontrol` are audio streams, not devices) except of your three. I vaguely remember I had some similar problem with `padsp` in the past (it created multiple streams when it should only create one), but it worked nevertheless just by ignoring the extra streams. I also had a quick look at `padsp.c`, and streams only seem to be created when I/O happens. That's probably why there's no playback stream (yet). It's possible that `padsp` changed since the blog entry was written, and something got screwed up in the process.

So pick one of the `OSS emulation[dsd]` streams under Record (these are the *inputs* of `dsd`, it has nothing to do with what you want to record), hook it up to the `.monitor` input of whatever sink `gqrx` is playing into, feed it with valid data (I can't do that here, because I don't know what data it expects, so I can't test), and see if you get a playback stream.

If you only want to playback the output of dsd in your hardware, create a virtual sink with

```
pacmd load-module module-null-sink sink_name=gqrx_to_dsd  sink_properties=device.description=GQRX-to-DSD
```

select this sink as output of `gqrx`, and the `.monitor` source of this sink as input of `dsd`. Then select your hardware audio sink as output of `dsd` (should you get a playback stream).

Comment: Hi thank-you for the information.  I do see three devices listed as "OSS emulation [dsd] but they are appearing under Recording, not Playback.  I want to listen to the audio over speakers or headphones, not record it.  So maybe there is a way to change them from Recording to Playback?  My system is obviously seeing the DSD audio.

Comment: Okay thank you I tried that.  I now see an audio sink that I can select in playback called GQRX_to_DSD.  But I still get no audio.

Comment: I tried adding the DSD sink under the recording part too... but still I get no audio from DSD.  When I turn down the squelch I get no audio either.

Comment: Do you have any sound file with valid DSD input that decodes to something, so I can test it here?

Comment: No, sorry I do not.  As I understand it the audio goes like this:                        SDR --> GQRX --> DSD --> Speakers  I still see the P25 Data going through console but I get no audio.

Comment: The point is that the `padsp` OSP emulation which DSD uses may only create a playback stream when DSD actually *outputs* audio. That means you have to feed DSD correct data it can synchronize on before you get anything you can connect to your speakers. And if you have invalid data, you may never get the playback stream. But I may be wrong, some other aspect of OSS emulation may be screwed up, so having valid input data for DSD would allow me to test it here.

Comment: Thanks for your help.  In the console I get less than a 0.25% BER on P25 and I know from programming radios that is very good and I am less than 1 mile from this repeater.  So my frequency is bang on and so you would think that it would be relaying audio?  FYI... I tried to install OP25 as well because I understand that it does P25 Phase 1 and 2 but I am running into build errors there.  I heard there was a GQRX with DSD built in floating around but I can no longer find it anywhere.

Comment: If you think it's relaying audio and has good data, can you capture something long enough I can test with (i.e., make sure DSD syncs and produces good data), and upload it somewhere? `parecord -d gqrx_to_dsd.monitor blah.wav`, possibly you'll have to add suitable `--channel`, `--format`, and/or `--rate`, see `man parecord`. I don't know what GQRX outputs.